# Android: How to change text size of KeyboardView?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have made a Custom keyboard to my application, and I would like to change the key's text size.

Is there any way to archive this? May be using themes or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I've found the KeyboardView property: `android:keyTextSize`

Comment: how do you change it programmatically?

Comment: but no effect on keypadview?